# Powering 3.5 inch LCD screen and RPi with 7.4V Lithium Polymer Battery

Tags: power, electronics

I am attempting to create a portable Raspberry Pi. I am wondering how I would go about running the RPi  and the LCD screen from the same battery. The screen draws about 6.5V. I have a 5V voltage regulator. Where would the best place be to attach the power supply? Would it be possible to have it powered through the micro USB slot? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say draws 6.5V do you mean the screen needs a 6.5V power supply?  It seems an odd working voltage.  Have you a link to the screen specs?  You could use a couple of buck converters to convert the LiPo to suitable screen and Pi voltages.  e.g. http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/351020297464

Comment: I mean it drops out about 6.5V. This is where I bought the [screen](http://www.amazon.co.uk/inch-Digital-Rear-Monitor-Square-Black/dp/B0056WJP1M/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1404748999&sr=8-2&keywords=lcd+screen#productDetails).
I think that has all the specs. I'll look into the buck converters

Comment: Those reversing screens normally work from the car's 12V system.  Are you saying it will work direct from the Li Po.  If so you just need a converter to provide 5V to the Pi from the Li Po.  I have a similar set-up.  A 12V laptop PSU powering a screen directly and also fed into a 5V UBEC which powers the Pi (via the P1 5V and ground pins).  The UBEC is similar in price but does not need calibrating (adjusting the output voltage by turning a screw).  It takes something like 5.5V-26V as an input and provides a 5V output.